# How align text in <caption> table to the left?

Tags: text, twitter-bootstrap, alignment, caption

Good day.

Code:

```
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
<caption class="pull-right">Pays</caption>
<thead>
```

What class in bootstrap.css would align text in `<caption>` to the left?

If may give me link on full description format text in `<caption>`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As of Bootstrap 2.3 released Feb 7th, there is now a built-in class to do this: see http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/PjZqE/

HTML

```
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
<caption class="text-left">Caption Left</caption>
```

See http://blog.getbootstrap.com/2013/02/07/bootstrap-2-3-released/ for full details of all the new features

Comment: taiaroa you dont see all my question. i ask `name class in bootstrap.css that align text in <caption>`. original name class not new created class.

Comment: See my updated answer. Until two days ago there wasn't a built-in class, but there is now.